# Updated TouchEvent Properties?

Tags: actionscript-3, api, actionscript, air, air-native-extension

Let's say I have this very simple function:

```
function pressingDown(e:TouchEvent):void
{
    trace(e.pressure);
}
```

As you can see, it will **trace** the pressure of the user's touch, but **how do I keep this updated?**

For example, the user doesn't move their finger *at all* and my program needs to detect the pressure of their touch *all the time.*  What **Touch Event** should I use for this?  Does it exist?  If it doesn't, what can I do to achieve what I'm asking for, or can I achieve it at all without a 3rd party library/ANE?

Answer (score 0):

I have never used e.pressure before, though I don't know this would work.
But might as well throw out some idea, in case it helps.

Try Event.ENTER_FRAME

```
package {

    public class TouchApp extends MovieClip {

       var _currentTouchEvent:TouchEvent;

        public function TouchApp()
        {
            this.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, pressingDown);
        }

        function pressingDown(e:TouchEvent):void
        {
            _currentTouchEvent = e;
            //When touch is down, do this function every frame.
            this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, whileBeingTouched);

            //Add EventListener to catch "touchEnd" event.
            this.stage.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, onTouchEndHandler);
        }

        function whileBeingTouched(evt:Event):void
        {
            //Action to do every frame.
            trace(_currentTouchEvent.pressure);
        }

        function onTouchEndHandler(e:TouchEvent):void
        {
            if (_currentTouchEvent) _currentTouchEvent = null;

            this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, whileBeingTouched);
            this.stage.removeEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, onTouchEndHandler);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, you cannot access Touch properties from an ENTER_FRAME Event